# Read value from SQLite Database and save value in a Variable

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-container

I'm having trouble getting some SQLite programming to work in Unity. I have a database with a couple of values and I want to take one of those values and store it as a variable. This is what I have so far:

```
public IDbConnection _dbc;
public IDbCommand _dbcm;
public IDataReader _dbr;

public string test2 = "";
public int test = 10;

_dbc = new SqliteConnection(_constr);
_dbc.Open();
_dbcm = _dbc.CreateCommand();
_dbcm.CommandText = "SELECT `Name` FROM `Classes` WHERE `HD`='"+test+"'";
_dbr = _dbcm.ExecuteReader();

while( _dbr.Read())
    test2 = _dbr.GetString(0);

print (test2);
_dbr.Close();
```

I've played around with it a bit, but so far the print reports no change in the value of test2, which is the variable I want to store the SQLite DB value in.

Comment: What datatype is the field "HD"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if this is a result of ambigious results returning.  Would executing a Scalar function not be more useful if you only want one result?  I don't know Unity well enough to say if GetString() will perform implicit conversion if result is not right type.

The following example is some old Visual Basic, but should show what I'm talking about.

```
Dim sqlConnect As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection
    sqlConnect.ConnectionString = MyStandAloneDB.DBConnStr
    Dim sqlCmd As SQLite.SQLiteCommand = sqlConnect.CreateCommand

        Try
            sqlConnect.Open()
Dim nme As String = CStr(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar)
            TextDbName.Text = nme
Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Finally
            sqlCmd.Dispose()
            sqlConnect.Close()
        End Try
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I think I'm gonna look into different solutions for databases now.